# Best way of synchronizing lots of threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, stress-testing

I develop an application, and, at a given moment, I start about 10000 threads to stress-test a database. I want to synchronize this in the following way: I want to read all data from a table in all the threads, then I want all the treads to wait for the other threads to stop reading. After all threads finished reading, I delete all records from that table, then I want all the threads to insert the data read previously. Now, how do I synchronize my threads, to wait for each other in the before mentioned order? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html):

> CyclicBarriers are useful in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must occasionally wait for each other.

The example in the JavaDoc quoted above solves the exact same problem.

---

10 thousand threads? Make sure you are testing your database, not your CPU and memory (context switching overhead might be tremendous). Have you considered [jmeter](/questions/tagged/jmeter) in distributed mode?

Answer (score 3):

This may not exactly be what you looking for, but you could give it a look [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

> A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a
>   set of operations being performed in other threads completes.